# Reviving newly laid buffalo sod

Tags: grass, rot

I have taken too many days to finish laying my turf.  After almost a week (with a night of rain in between), the pallets of sods that have been sitting on the garage driveway are in very bad condition.  When I unroll these final batches of sod they were wet and easily ripped or pulled apart, and now it's been almost 3 weeks after they were laid and I still observe no root and the blades are all still looking flat and dry.

My questions are:

1. were they rotten already while rolled up and pressed for more than 5 days?
2. Is it possible to see regrowth on these areas where sods were laid toward the end of the project? As a side note, the edge of these sods still shows good growth (these edge growth were developed back while they were in the rolled up stage).

I don't know what to do at the moment, especially when it comes to mowing the lawn because 2/3 of my turf looks like they will be ready to be mown in a month or two but the remaining 1/3 only show edge growth so far.

Please advice if I should reorder sods and replace these areas or if it is just a matter of time before signs of overall growth.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Howard, Its s bit hard to say without pictures